# Enable Alt+Left/Right in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS to jump words (like Ctrl+Left/Right by default)

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I am trying to somewhat mimic some mac controls in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS: specifically using `ctrl`+`left`/`right` to jump to the beginning/end of a line and `alt`+`left`/`right` to jump a word backward/forward. I'm running into the issue of not being able to properly set `alt`+`left`/`right` for forward-word/backward-word respectively. I got it to run within VSCode thanks to its own coprehensive settings configuration and on the terminal via `.zshrc`. However, for other applications (Teams, Chrome, ..), i.e. globally, I had no success in finding somewhere the option to configure this properly.

So far, I tried to look into the Keyboard Shortcut OS settings and into `dconf-editor`, but with no success. Furthermore I use [AutoKey](https://autokey.github.io/api.html) to mimic some mac functionality (`ctrl`+`left`/`right` to jump to beginning/end of line), however, for moving a word back/forward, I wasn't able to find a command that allows that behaviour via `AutoKey`. `xmodmap` and `xbindkeys` both seem to not help, because they don't allow modifier mapping to this specific operation as far as I am aware.

What other options are there available to map these commands OS-wide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually got a working solution with `AutoKey`. The "trick" was to map `alt`+`left` to `ctrl`+`left` to get the backward-word behaviour (and vice-versa for `right` and forward), thanks to not recursively linking to the changed behaviour of `ctrl`+ `left`.

Some notes on `AutoKey`:

- using a `script` was very slow with a noticable lag between input and output => using a `phrase` mitigated this issue and is blitz-fast
- to get `alt`+`left` for backward jumping one word I used: `<ctrl>+<left>` as the phrase
- to get the behaviour of `shift`+`home` with `ctrl`+`shift`+`left` I used: `<shift>+<home>`
- to get the behaviour of `home` with `ctrl`+`left` I used: `<home>`

All of the above examples work with the counterpart `right` and `<end>` similarly.

Finally, since I had already adapted the `VSCode` and `terminal` settings to mimic this behaviour, I used the `Window Filter` functionality in `AutoKey` to apply these `phrases` only to other applications.